# File isn't deleted when code is in a specific order

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I ran into the problem that when I try to delete a record from database using `->delete()` and my code stopped after successfully deleted the record.

This code doesn't execute the `Storage::delete($image)`

```
public function productImageDelete(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()):
        $image_id = Input::get('image-id');
        $image = Input::get('image');
        try {
            $image = Image::findOrFail($image_id);
            $image->delete();
            Storage::delete($image); //This doesn't execute at all
            return "success";
        } catch ( \Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
            return $e;
        }
    endif;
}
```

However when I placed `Storage::delete($image)` before `$image->delete();` the code works.

```
public function productImageDelete(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()):
        $image_id = Input::get('image-id');
        $image = Input::get('image');
        try {
            Storage::delete($image); //This executes first
            $image = Image::findOrFail($image_id);
            $image->delete();
            return "success";
        } catch ( \Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
            return $e;
        }
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at the details. You're creating two variables named `$image` and that's your issue.

On the first case, you're calling `Storage::delete($image);` where `$image` is an object and on the second case, you're calling the same method but in that case `$image` is a `Input::get('image')`.

If you simply rename the variable of `Input::get('image')` to, say `$imageParam = Input::get('image')` and execute `Storage::delete($imageParam);`, it should work on both cases.

The bottomline is: never use the same variable name, as it will led to such unnecessary confusions.

Comment: Ty i realized that now